# Closed form of this arithmetic series?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am computing the partial sums $s_{nn}$ of a series given by

$a_{ij} = {1 \over 2}^{j-i}$ if $j>i$, $a_{ij} = -1$ if $j=i$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ if $j < i$

The $s_{nn}$ is the partial sum $\sum_{i,j =1}^n a_{ij}$. I computed that $$s_{nn}=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k) {1 \over 2^k}$$

and now I am trying to find a closed formula for $s_{nn}$ but I'm stuck. Please can someone help me how to do this?

Comment: Funny to offer a bounty for one of the most duplicated questions on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your expression $s_{nn} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k) {1 \over 2^k}$ is correct, I work from there.

$$s_{nn} = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k) {1 \over 2^k} = n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{1 \over 2^k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k \over 2^k}$$

As the first term is clearly a geometric series, I focus on the latter term.

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k \over 2^k} = \frac{1}{2} + (\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4}) + (\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}) + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}} $$

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k \over 2^k} = (\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}) + (\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}) + (\frac{1}{8} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}) + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} $$

Which is a sum of geometric series. Plugging in the closed form expression for each individual series will result in another geometric series, finally providing the partial sum.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $s_{nn}$ is decomposed to $A_n=n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{2^k}$ and $B_n=-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac k{2^k}$. $A_n$ is geometric series and $B_n$ can be converted to geometric series by considering $2B_n-B_n$.

To expand $2B_n-B_n$, note that
$$\begin{align}&\frac1{2^1}+\frac2{2^2}+\frac3{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{n-2}{2^{n-2}}+\frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}\\
-\frac1{2^0}-&\frac2{2^1}-\frac3{2^2}-\frac4{2^3}-\cdots-\frac{n-1}{2^{n-2}}\\
=-\frac1{2^0}-&\frac1{2^1}-\frac1{2^2}-\frac1{2^3}-\cdots-\frac{1}{2^{n-2}}+\frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you but I still don't see. How is 
$$ kB_n - B_n = -\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k^2 \over 2^k}  + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k \over 2^k}= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k-k^2 \over 2^k}  $$
a geometric series?

Comment: @blue Try to expand them and you will find the law therein.

Comment: By expand do you mean to do $k - k^2 = k (1-k)$?

Comment: @blue I mean expand to $-1/2-4/4-9/8\ldots$ rather than $\sum k^2/2^k$.

Comment: I don't understand. I expanded both $\sum k^2 / 2^k$ and $\sum (k-k^2)/2^k$ and neither is a geometric series. What should I do?

Comment: @blue Sorry, I made a mistake. See my expansion now.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** Differentiating the geometric series identity, we have

$$1+x+\cdots +x^n= \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\implies1+2x+3x^2+\cdots +nx^{n-1}= \frac{d}{dx}\left( \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\right)=\frac{(n+1)x^n (x-1)-x^{n+1}+1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Put $x=\frac{1}{2}:$

$$
1+2\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)+3\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\cdots +n \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}=4-\frac{n+2}{2^{n-1}}
$$

Comment: I computed this sum twice and both times I got $2 - {n+1 \over 2^{n-1}}$